# add data in a dictionary and print it with python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, setdefault

hello all I'm just learning python and i have a problem.
I want to add the results of a network request inside a dictionary in python and then . I want to download the movie title and id of all the movies on a movie site and put it inside a dictionary. Since the dictionary key must be unique, I thought of creating an "original_title" key where I put all the titles of the movies and another "id" key where I put the id of all the movies. This is my code:

```
dictionary={}
for i in range(1,36590):
    response1 = requests.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/moie?api_key=mykey&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page="+str(i)+"&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate")
    jsonresponse1=response1.json()
    results=jsonresponse1["results"]
    for result in results:
        dictionary.setdefault("original_title", [])
        dictionary.setdefault("id", [])
        dictionary['original_title'].append(result["original_title"])
        dictionary['id'].append(result["id"])      
print(dictionary)
```

why doesn't my code work? How can I print the dictionary, after adding the data downloaded from the website?

Comment: Are you sure that the request is working? In `response1 = requests.get("https:www.movies.it")` it doesn't look like `https:www.movies.it` is a valid URL. Try changing it to `https://www.movies.it`.

Comment: Your URL is wrong

Comment: A few things: URL is wrong (should be https:// ), even with that, I see that the www.movies.it is not working... Lastly, why would you want to do it 36590 times?

Comment: your code will launch 36590 consecutive requests to that website without any delay between them. I'm guessing the server will block your requests and blacklist your IP as a DDoS attack after a few hundred queries.

Comment: Did you notice the InvalidURL exception when you ran this?

Comment: I made a mistake in copying the network request url. Now I edited the post, but the code still doesn't work

Comment: Hi ! There are way too many requests. 36k is a lot, and you're sure to be blocked quickly. You should look for a way to get a batch of objects according to a filter or something !
A good practice would be to try with a very small sample (one request, for example) and print it, just to be sure that the request works.
Good luck !